# как в perl использовать ссылки на файлы с двойным слеш \\?

Tags: perl, ссылки

Есть ссылка на диск, например:

\link\

```
print '\\link';
```

результат получается:

\link

а мне нужен:

\\link Чтобы ссылка работала корректно

как этого добиться наиболее оптимальным способом?

Comment: хм... попробуйте ```\\\\link```

Comment: Ну четыре слеша возьмите `\\\\link`, один слеш экранирует идущий следом символ

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
use syntax 'raw_quote';
my $string1 = r'a\\\b';
print $string1; # prints 'a\\\b'
```

Вот тут подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331653/how-can-i-prevent-perl-from-interpreting-double-backslash-as-single-backslash-ch